# How to install Symfony 2.7?

Tags: git, symfony, composer-php, symfony-2.7

The latest stable release of Symfony is 2.6.6 However, I would like to add some code to a core component. I have forked the repo and can clone it locally, but it is only the Symfony core. I need the full framework complete with AcmeDemoBundle so that I can run and test any changes.

The [Symfony page](http://symfony.com/doc/2.7/book/installation.html#book-creating-applications-without-the-installer) recommends using the installer, but that only works for stable releases. On the same page, it gives the composer method of installing, but composer cannot find a 2.7 version.

How can I install the (currently dev) Symfony 2.7 framework-standard?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As symfony/framework-standard-edition is not a typical dependency but used to bootstrap projects, it's best to install it via the create-project command:

```
composer create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition project_name
```

If you want a 2.7 version you would typically do this:

```
composer create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition project_name '2.7.*'
```

However since at the time of this writing there is no 2.7 stable, you need to lower the stability to dev:

```
composer create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition project_name '2.7.*' -s dev
```

`-s` being short for `--stability`.

Comment: I had forgotten the '@dev' requirement, stupid me :/

Answer (score 3):

```
 composer create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition project_name '2.7.*@dev'
```

Comment: This should actually be marked as the right answer, since it's the proper way to get SF2 to kick start its bootstrap process.

Answer (score -1):

When I try to execute the following command

`composer create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition project_name '2.7'`

composer return this error:

`[UnexpectedValueException]
Could not parse version constraint '2.7': Invalid version string "'2.7'"`

You should install without single cotes:

`composer create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition project_name 2.7`